# Microsoft Excel 2013 - IF not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following IF formula:

```
=IF(O2>=9,"Level 3",IF(O2>=6,"Level 2",IF(O2>=3,"Level 1",IF(O2>=0,"Level 0"))))
```

All my answers come up with Level 3.

Column O has *Years Employed*, so I want to group these into 4 tiers. 0-3, 3-6, 6-9, & 9 and up.

Comment: People can only guess without knowing what is in O2.

Answer (score 0):

This formula appears to work, though as-is, it actually counts 0-2, 3-5, 6-8 and 9+ (assuming that is acceptable).

Offhand, it sounds as if you possibly haven't adjusted the value of `O2` to match the rest of the cells in your sheet properly when you copied the formula (e.g. for Row 3, you would use `O3` not `O2`).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the O-column is not set as a text (select the column and choose cell properties, or Ctrl+1). A character will always equate higher than a number in Excel.